# Best place to make a UIView subclass round

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a UIView subclass that needs to be round. The issue I am having is that
this view is instantiated with frame `.zero` (and eventually resized) which produces a `cornerRadius` of 0 when calling `makeRound` in the initializer.

Which UIView lifecycle method should I call `makeRound` and assume `layer.bounds` has adopted its final value (which is non-zero)?

```
fileprivate extension UIView {
    func makeRound() {
        layer.cornerRadius = layer.bounds.width*0.5
        clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

The only UIView subclass initializer I can use is

```
    public init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        // init routines
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would either override the `bounds` property or override the `layoutSubviews` method.

```
class SomeView: UIView {
    // Either do this:
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = bounds.size.height / 2.0
            // or call makeRound()
        }
    }

    // Or do this:
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.size.height / 2.0
        // or call makeRound()
    }
}
```

Don't do both. Pick the one of the two.